# Run CSS on sibling if other sibling has class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to do the following in pure css. If my `rds-trigger-button` has the class active I want the `tab` div to be visible, otherwise be hidden.

html:

```
<div>
   <div class="rds-trigger-button"><span class="rds-carrot">&#9660;</span> Learn More</div>
   <div class="tab">
       Cardigan organic four loko, Etsy art party Godard jean shorts. Chillwave next level letterpress lumbersexual wolf jean shorts, church-key ugh vegan typewriter PBR four loko. Occupy whatever chillwave, pug tote bag organic migas High Life hoodie flannel Schlitz small batch distillery DIY.
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.rds-trigger-button{
    border: 1px blue solid;
    width:100px;
    padding:12px;
    position:relative;
}
.rds-trigger-button.active{
    border-bottom:1px white solid;
    z-index:9999;
}
.rds-trigger-button.active + .tabs{
    display:block !important;
}
.rds-carrot{
    font-size:10px;
    color:#ccc;
    padding-right:8px;
}
.tab{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-1px;
    width:356px;
    background-color:#fff;
    min-height:50px;
    padding:24px;
    border: 1px #2E51A1 solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0sqoaxxs/2/

Comment: You have already answered your question; Using adjacent sibling selector `A + B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplified code would be:

```
.tab {
  display: none;
}
.rds-trigger-button.active + .tab {
  display: block;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zh983f3p/)

In the code you posted above, you are using the selector `.rds-trigger-button.active + .tabs`. Since the element's class is `.tab` (singular), and not `.tabs`, it wasn't being applied. In addition, you were also using the selector `.rds-trigger-button.active > .tabs` in your example you posted. It wasn't working for the same reason *and* because `.tab` isn't a direct child of `.rds-trigger-button.active`.

To clarify, `+` is an [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators). As the name implies, it will select the immediate, adjacent sibling element.

In some instances, you may also be interested in the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Comment: @LucaDeCaprio Yes. It's a CSS 2.1 selector, therefore it is supported in IE7 and higher http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2 ..

Answer (score 1):

Remove the s at the end of `.rds-trigger-button.active + .tabs` to get .tab  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS

```
.active ~ .tab{
   display: block;
}
```